# How to fix 500.1002 error in Azure?

Tags: node.js, azure, express, iisnode

We have 500.1001 or 500.1002 errors after success building our app. We tried to bundle our app to root and to public - error 500. We tried to correct iisnode.yml parameters (maxNamedPipeConnectionRetry and namedPipeConnectionRetryDelay). Our app always on in server.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<webSocket enabled="false" />

<handlers>
  <add name="iisnode" path="/public/server.bundle.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
</handlers>

<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^server.bundle.js\/debug[\/]?" />
    </rule>

    <rule name="StaticContent">
      <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}"/>
    </rule>

    <rule name="DynamicContent">
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/public/server.bundle.js"/>
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>

<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <hiddenSegments>
      <remove segment="bin"/>
    </hiddenSegments>
  </requestFiltering>
</security>

<httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
```

Answer (score -5, accepted):

We found the solution. Just migrated to VM with Linux.

Comment: I don't think `Switch to Linux` solves the problem of `How to fix 500.1002 error in Azure`.

Comment: That's not a solution, maybe the configuration works in case of linux. I'm also facing the same issue